# Nash equilibrium for Bertrand Model with Spatial Differentiation

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider a town with consumers represented by a closed interval $[0,2]$ with the consumers spread continuously and uniformly. There are two stores, $A$ and $B$ who sell the same product at $p_A$ and $p_B$ at no cost.

A consumer has a gross utility of 4 from having the product which is reduced by price paid and travel costs, which is determined as distance traveled. Each consumer only buys 1 unit of the product, and if the consumer does not buy from either store, he has a utility of 0. For example, if a consumer is located at $x=1.5$ and buys from store B at $p_B=1$ which is located at $x_B=2$, then his utility is $4-1-|2-1.5| = 2.5$.

Suppose that $A$ is located at $x_A=0$ and $B$ is located at $x_B=2$. Also, suppose stores much charge at $p \le 4$.

Suppose stores are profit maximizers. What are the equilibrium prices, quantities, and profits for both stores?

---

My initial thoughts are that, in this scenario, the profit functions for each store is denoted as:

$$ \pi_A=p_A+p_A(\frac{p_B-p_A}{2}) $$

$$ \pi_B=p_B-p_B(\frac{p_B-p_A}{2}) $$

We can take the first order condition for each, to get the maximizing profit.

$$ \frac{\partial \pi_A}{p_A} = 1 + \frac{p_B}{2} - p_A = 0 \implies p_A = \frac{p_B}{2} + 1 $$

$$ \frac{\partial \pi_B}{p_B} = 1 - p_B + \frac{p_A}{2} = 0 \implies p_B = 1 + \frac{p_A}{2} $$

By substituting one into the other, we have that $p_A=p_B=2$, $q_A=q_B=1$ and $\pi_A=\pi_B=2$.

I'm not very sure about this solution or the direction I took to solve it. Any advice here would be appreciated on what other direction I should try.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version of **Hotelling's Model of Spatial Differentiation**

The easiest solution to this is to find an "X" in-between [0,2] such that the customer is indifferent between going to Firm A or Firm B.

This will happen when 
$ P(A) + Distance(X-A) - Utility = P(B) + Distance(B-X) - Utility $

Then demand [0, X] would go to A, and demand [X, 2] will go to B. Then using Best Response Functions for this Simultaneous game we can compute prices, quantity, and profits.

I have attached my solution below. For more information, you can see -  [SNYDER NICHOLSON HOTELLING'S BEACH EXAMPLE](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=DXcJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA544&lpg=PA544&dq=snyder%20nicholson%20hotelling&source=bl&ots=RWmQxfSq2W&sig=ACfU3U3WC_orI1OuFUPLrukZ7N5PNDyOPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7ofWa2ZLpAhXRzTgGHQBtCIcQ6AEwBHoECAsQAQ)
[image]
[image]